# How can I set the value for a select2 on a nightwatch test?

Tags: nightwatch.js

If you can show an example with Page Objects would be great.
The commented line should set a value for a select tag that has been replaced with a jquery select2.

```
module.exports = {

  'Profile step': (client) => {
    const profile = client.page.profile();

    profile.navigate()
      .waitForElementVisible('@editProfileButton', 10000)
      .click('@editProfileButton')
      .waitForElementVisible('@location', 2000)
      .setValue('@location', 'Germany')
      //.setSelect2Value('@timezone', '445')
      .setValue('@website', 'www.pypage.com')
      .click('@saveProfileButton');
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "click" instead of "setValue", something like this:

```
.click('.select2-results__option[data-value="Germany"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same situation.  One thing to note is that select2 is responsive to the underlying select that you have bound it to.  So if you change the select value there the select2 field will respond.

In my case I used the same method as Vincent Garraeau with the exception that I am doing it by id rather than class.

```
.click('select[id="SELECT_ID"] option[value="TARGET_VALUE"]');
```

The selector targets the select by its id (select_id) and then it clicks the selects option that has the value of target_value.